# How do I break a long table cell/row using the europecv package?

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table environment that can break inside a cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/table-environment-that-can-break-inside-a-cell)

Using the `europecv` package to typeset my CV, I mostly use the `\ecvitem` command which. The whole Europass CV is built around a table with 2 columns and the `\ecvitem` command has 2 arguments, the first one for the first column and the other for the second.

The problem is that if one cell/row is very long, the page break does not happen. Instead, the whole content is pushed to the next page. Here is a sample document:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{europecv}
        \ecvsection{Section}
        \ecvitem{Item}{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \lipsum[1]
                \item \lipsum[2]
            \end{itemize}}
    \end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result: [image: http://imm.io/DmHs]

How can I the text on the first page and make it break when reaching the page break and continue on the next page? Preferably without manually splitting the text into a new row.

Comment: I remember a similar (more general) question regarding breaking a single cell across a page in `longtable`. The answer was that this is not possible. See, for example, [Table environment that can break inside a cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11149/5764). @DavidCarlisle will be able to give a definitive answer. Do you have other options besides [`europecv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/europecv)?

Comment: No, it must be `europecv`... :(

Comment: If that's a longtable internally you need to manually split up up into two cells, you can not break the page mid row.