# Custom table with mdframed and parcolumns: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: tables, mdframed, parcolumns

I am building my own table environment using parcolumns and mdframed.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{mytable}[1]
   {\begin{mdframed}[splittopskip=0pt,frametitle={},frametitlerule=true,frametitlebelowskip=0pt,frametitleaboveskip=0pt,roundcorner=0pt,skipabove=0pt,leftline=true,rightline=true,innertopmargin=-4pt,innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,middlelinewidth=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,everyline=true,splitbottomskip=0pt]
    \hspace{0pt}
    \begin{parcolumns}[rulebetween,sloppy]{#1}}
   {\end{parcolumns}
    \end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mytable}{2}
\colchunk{Some text}\colchunk{Some more text}\colplacechunks
\hrule
\colchunk{Yet more text}\colchunk{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.}\colplacechunks
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

It properly handles long paragraphs within table cells, which none of the existing table libraries do (please correct me, I would love to be wrong here).

The following things are not clear to me:

- If I define the environment header as `\begin{mdframed}[...]\begin{parcolumns}[...]` (i.e. without the `\hspace`), I get `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` Why is this?
- Adding `\hspace{0pt}` stops the error, but causes the top border of the mdframed to be about 4pt too high, hence why I need `innertopmargin=-4pt`. Does hspace have a height? Is there a different invisible character I could use for this purpose?

p.s. I am aware of the lipsum package but do not have it installed, hence the pasted text.